# Ubuntu apache htaccess custom url for seo friendly not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

I ned to change this url

```
https://halopredictions.com/blog/index.php?url=german-bundesliga-prepare-to-return-on-9-may
```

to

```
https://halopredictions.com/blog/german-bundesliga-prepare-to-return-on-9-may
```

This is my .htaccess that am currently using

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ index.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
```

I have already enabled mod rewrite
The htaccess is on this path `...\blog\.htaccess`

Any help I will highly appreciate

Comment: Your Htaccess Does Almost The Opposite of What You Asked to. It Converts `https://halopredictions.com/blog/german-bundesliga-prepare-to-return-on-9-may` to `https://halopredictions.com/index.php?url=blog/german-bundesliga-prepare-to-return-on-9-may`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained This Will Help You!

Answer (score 0):

Before proceeding with the answer, if I understand correctly you want to redirect from `https://halopredictions.com/blog/german-bundesliga-prepare-to-return-on-9-may` To `https://halopredictions.com/blog/index.php?url=german-bundesliga-prepare-to-return-on-9-may`.

Since SEO Urls are used by the visitors, we have to convert them to actual path.
The below RewriteRule will be sufficient to achieve the above condition.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^blog/([A-Za-z0-9-\+]+)/?$ blog/index.php?url=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Explanation:

`^blog/([A-Za-z0-9-\+]+)/?$` - This part is what you want to rewrite from. Since, your URLs will be like in the pattern `https://halopredictions.com/blog/german-bundesliga-prepare-to-return-on-9-may`, we need to get the url part after `blog/`.
I have used a regular expression `([A-Za-z0-9-\+]+)/?` to match the url part and it can be referrenced using `$1`.

Now we have to use `$1` in our new url. For that, we have written the second part of RewriteRule where you can assign the referrence.
`blog/index.php?url=$1` - Now, as you would assume we are using the `$1` reference after `index.php?url=`, so that it will append it to the URL Query param and should lead to a valid path.

By the way, `^` this is used to indicate the start and `$` for the end.

Comment: Can you further explain what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: I am using GET method to get the content from the DB `https://halopredictions.com/blog/index.php?url=german-bundesliga-prepare-to-return-on-9-may`. As you can see am **Selecting from the db where url = german-bundesliga-prepare-to-return-on-9-may.** But I don't want viewers to see it that way, instead to see it this way `https://halopredictions.com/blog/german-bundesliga-prepare-to-return-on-9-may`

Comment: Are you using any framework? URL and DB don't have any relation between them. When you perform a GET request, the language PHP is making the Query to the Database and Showing the Data to the User. The URL is not anyway related with the Database.

Comment: Thank you. Now what is your recommendation on this so that I can achieve that. Maybe another way to do it

Comment: Can you mention the Folder Structure?

Comment: `html > blog > index.php`

Comment: If `html` is your project folder then put `index.php` in the web-root. That is, `html > index.php`. Then you can create a blog post inside the `blog` directory. ie; `html > blog > blog-post.php`. 

So when you redirect from `index.php` to Blog post, you will get the desired URL. 
But I think you should create some Routing Service, if you want to go forward with this.
Alternatively, you can use Free Libraries or Frameworks in PHP to solve the issue.
I am still not sure why you need to `reinvent` the wheel!

Comment: I got you. Thanks